# How to change Instance Collation of sql server running on amazon rds?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sql-server-2008-r2, amazon-rds

I'm running SQL Server 2008R2 Standard edition on and RDS instance. I need to change the server's collation.So how can i change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.SQLServer.CommonDBATasks.Collation):

> Amazon RDS creates a default server collation for character sets when
> a SQL Server DB instance is created. This default server collation is
> currently English (United States), or more precisely,
> SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.
>
> **You can change the default collation at the database, table, or column level by overriding the collation when creating a new database or database object.** For example, you can change from the default collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS to Japanese_CI_AS for Japanese collation support. Even arguments in a query can be type-cast to use a different collation if necessary.

So change to desired collation on

- [database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx)

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE db_name
  COLLATE collate_name;
  ```
- [column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx)

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.table_name ALTER COLUMN col_name
  type COLLATE collate_name;
  ```

Comment: The words "default" and "currently" in the sentance _This default server collation is currently English (United States)_ imply to me that you ought to be able to change the server collation but the sentence in bold certainly contradicts that! IMHO, this is a big limitation with an AWS RDS hosted implementation of SQL Server, especially when restoring backups of legacy applications you want to port to AWS. I'm currently wrestling to resolve this :(